# What does sdptool do in this script?

Tags: linux, shell

Here I want to know about this `sdptool` command does in the following script snippet:

```
if [ `sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l` -lt 5 ]
```

I understand `sdptool browse $BD_ADDR` as well as `wc -l` -- it's used for new line counts in result of `sdptool browse $BD_ADDR`.

but what about `-lt 5`?

Answer (score 5):

`-lt 5` means "lesser than 5".

So the *if* body will execute if sdptool returns less than 5 lines.

Comment: here in C How can i store return value of 'sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l'. i am using system call so system call return 0 on success but how can i store word count return value so i will compare with less than 5

Comment: See the [popen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) function.

Comment: Alternatively you could `system("sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l > output.txt");` and then read output.txt with fopen.

Comment: popen return the output of this command?

Comment: popen is return the I/O Strem of this process but i have to read that value so may be its not useful.

Comment: can i not use if(a=system("sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l > output.txt") < 5) ?

Comment: No, `system` returns the exit code of the command, not its output.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the breakdown of

```
if [ `sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l` -lt 5 ]
```

1. `if`: the beginning of a shell if-statement
2. `[`: this is actually a command. It is an alias for the `test` command
3. `: this is the beginning of command substitution
4. `sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l`: returns the number of lines output by `sdptool`
5. `: the end of the command substitution
6. `-lt 5`: this is an argument to the `test` command mentioned earlier. The output of the command substitution (the number of lines output by `sdptool`) is compared to 5 and returns `true` if less-than or `false` otherwise

Comment: here in C How can i store return value of 'sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l'. i am using system call so system call return 0 on success but how can i store word count return value so i will compare with less than 5

Comment: you will want to use `popen()` and `pclose()` which returns a `FILE *` to a pipe that runs the commands you pass in.  You could then use something like `fgets()` to read that `FILE *` into a character buffer

Comment: can i not use if(a=system("sdptool browse $BD_ADDR | wc -l > output.txt") < 5) ?

Comment: `man 3 system` and read what the return value is. It is *not* the output of the command being run

Comment: ok thanx so i have to compulsary use popen

Answer (score 0):

`[` is the unix command test, see the documentation `man test`.
The option `-lt` means

```
   INTEGER1 -lt INTEGER2

      INTEGER1 is less than INTEGER2
```

So your command checks whether the number of lines is < 5.

Answer (score 0):

The `-lt` argument to `[`/`test` performs an arithmetic comparison of the two arguments around it, returning true if the preceding argument is an integer less than the following argument.